# Is it important not to have unused class imports in Objective - C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compiler-construction

I want to **#import** my custom class in **"ProjectName"-Prefix.pch** file in Xcode project.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "CustomClass.h"
#endif
```

But, I won't use my custom class in every project file, so I want to know, will it somehow hurt to my app performance or something else?

Is there any problem with that?
Is it not recommended?

Comment: You can club the most used files in one file and put it into the `prefix` class. This will improve code readibility. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#import` ensures that a given header file is only ever actually included once, so there'll be performance issue. From Apple's documentation:

> When you want to include header files in your source code, you typically use a `#import` directive. This is like `#include`, except that it makes sure that the same file is never included more than once. The Objective-C samples and documentation all prefer the use of `#import`, and your own code should too.

From [Learning Objective C: A Primer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Performance for sure will not be affected. It is not a good practice to include header files in there unless they are used very broadly in your application, because it will render the code harder to read for people not familiar with your classes.